# Monerod failing at/after block 1383366

Tags: monerod

I downloaded 0.11.1 on a clean PC, fresh install, and have been doing a full sync.  The daemon is stuck at 1383366.  I have rebooted the PC a couple times to see if that will help, but it has not.  The monerod log:

This is on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine:

---

```
2018-02-12 18:00:49.125 [P2P5]  ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3276 Block with id: <613d4f611ab7c99a8b609e228e4f97ed4b94052fa51b835fa5704b1777b70c51> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <deee58332d46c354aaa9394585bf8104edfe61472164a38499fed3b8a4a5f800>
2018-02-12 18:01:42.140 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:305     [182.255.68.112:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1383366 -> 1508110 [Your node is 124744 blocks (173 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-02-12 18:01:48.812 [P2P4]  ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3276 Block with id: <613d4f611ab7c99a8b609e228e4f97ed4b94052fa51b835fa5704b1777b70c51> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <deee58332d46c354aaa9394585bf8104edfe61472164a38499fed3b8a4a5f800>
2018-02-12 18:02:18.156 [P2P4]  ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3276 Block with id: <613d4f611ab7c99a8b609e228e4f97ed4b94052fa51b835fa5704b1777b70c51> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <deee58332d46c354aaa9394585bf8104edfe61472164a38499fed3b8a4a5f800>
2018-02-12 18:02:25.000 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:305     [69.28.32.73:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1383366 -> 1508112 [Your node is 124746 blocks (173 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-02-12 18:02:29.453 [P2P3]  ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3276 Block with id: <613d4f611ab7c99a8b609e228e4f97ed4b94052fa51b835fa5704b1777b70c51> attempting to add transaction already in blockchain with id: <deee58332d46c354aaa9394585bf8104edfe61472164a38499fed3b8a4a5f800>
```

Comment: Thanks to assylias for editing to make it more readable.  Anyone have an idea what I can do to get this sync'd properly?